# Entity Framework CORE - generates sql select for each row

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use EF Core 1.1.2. I have that query:

```
var tmp = _context.Notes
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Note = x,
                CommentsCount = x.Comments.Count(y => y.Status == 1)
            }).ToList();
```

I would like to have one query to database but I have many for each note:

```
SELECT [x].[NoteId], [x].[Content], [x].[Title]
FROM [Notes] AS [x]

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Comments] AS [y1]
WHERE ([y1].[Status] = 1) AND (@_outer_NoteId = [y1].[NoteId])',N'@_outer_NoteId int',@_outer_NoteId=13

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Comments] AS [y1]
WHERE ([y1].[Status] = 1) AND (@_outer_NoteId = [y1].[NoteId])',N'@_outer_NoteId int',@_outer_NoteId=14

// and much more for each note
```

Is it a bug in EF Core 1.1.2 ?

Comment: How do you set your entities? fluent api or data annotations

Comment: data annotations

Comment: Can you show how you have settings for you entities ?

Comment: Is your LINQ query valid? Yes (and I would say it's pretty basic). Hence yes, it *is a bug*.